# How to make an Entity Framework property NOT NULL, but not required in form submission

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, foreign-keys

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 with a code-first model. A common pattern is that many objects reference the user who owns them, eg.

```
public class Item
{
    public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

This creates a nullable column in the DB, but since every Item must have an owner I want the column marked NOT NULL. If I use the `[Required]` attribute then submitting the form to create an Item results in an error. That field is never set through a form, only manually in code.

Answer (score 3):

It is generally recommended to create separate view models for such situations. Using database models as view models for input forms is seen as an anti-pattern.

Make a `ItemViewModel` that has the same properties as `Item` and relevant data validation attributes. You may want to use a library called [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper#readme) to automate the boring property-copy-code needed in those cases.

Comment: Thanks, but that sounds like it will create more problems than it will solve. And the problem I want to solve is really a minor one. So, the anti-pattern aside, is there any other way to mark the column "not null"?

Comment: @EM Your EF model is the gatekeeper to the database. If anything is required you mark it required. A view model is the way to go here. Solutions, even small ones, nowadays usually contain lots of view models and DTO's. Organization is the key.